# How do I transpose data in a Google Sheets and keep the formatting?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting

If we select a empty line and we type:

```
=TRANSPOSE(A1:C27)
```

We will invert everything from A1 to C27. However, formatting will be lost.

Is there any way to keep the format too?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To preserve the data and the formatting:

- go to **Edit**
- choose **Paste special**
- choose **Paste transpose (A1:C27)**

Comment: Oww! This actually works. But it is a bit cryptic. Just 
 a - select the cells you want;
 b - copy;
 c - go to where you want to paste;
 d - select 'paste: transpose';

Comment: What? this does not keep the destination format